# How do I convert local time to a Unix timestamp in Perl?

Tags: perl, unix

For example: from date: `10/02/2010`

How do I convert an equal timestamp for `10/02/2010 00:00:00` in Perl?

I can't use local time or time .. is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Date::Parse](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-1.20/lib/Date/Parse.pm):

```
use Date::Parse;
print str2time('10/02/2010 00:00:00');
```

On my machine this prints 1285970400, which [corresponds](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) to October 2nd, 2010 (I live in +1 GMT with +1 Wintertime.)

Comment: Shouldn't something be said about (different) date formats?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`Time::Local`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html) core module:

```
use Time::Local 'timelocal';
my ($d, $m, $y) = split '/', '10/02/2010';
my $time = timelocal(0, 0, 0, $d, $m-1, $y);
```

Note that the month argument for `timelocal()` is in the range `0..11`.

Answer (score 8):

Without localtime():

```
use Time::Local;
$time = timelocal($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year);
```

(See [perldoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Programming_Documentation).)

A standard way would be something like:

```
use POSIX;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $sec  = 0;
my $min  = 0;
my $hour = 0;
my $day  = 10;
my $mon  = 2 - 1;
my $year = 2010 - 1900;
my $wday = 0;
my $yday = 0;

my $unixtime = mktime ($sec, $min, $hour, $day, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday);
print "$unixtime\n";

my $readable_time = localtime($unixtime);
print "$readable_time\n"
```

(From *[Converting Unix time and readable time with Perl](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/perl/posix/convert_time.html)*)

Comment: thanks, good to note that mktime regards timezone while eg Time::Piece->strptime() not, in other words if you summed up years, months, days, hours etc passed parameters, and multiplied it with numbers in passed in parameters, it would not match for mktime, which is good, because it regards timezone

Answer (score 3):

I think you want the built-in module [Time::Local](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html).

Answer (score 2):

The [DateTime](http://datetime.perl.org/) module should be helpful here.  In particular, I believe the [DateTime::Format::Natural](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime-Format-Natural/lib/DateTime/Format/Natural.pm) module can parse a user-supplied date string.  From there, you have a DateTime object and can print it out or transform it as you like.

Comment: The DateTime module is extremely flexible and is my preferred choice for complex date and time manipulations (in particular, calculating sunrise and sunset for different locations when I travel around the world). However DateTime is heavy-weight and has a lot of dependencies. So if it's simplicity you want then using the built-in Time::Local module might be an approach to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where your initial date is coming from you might be able to parse it using

> Date::Manip

and calling

> ParseDate("10/02/2010")

You can then take that output and convert it into whatever format you wish.